# Forming rational numbers using unique Egyptian fractions

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms

**Question:** For a given rational number $r\in (0,1)$, does there exists a finite, ordered set $S\subset \mathbb{N}$ such that the product of the first $k$ elements of $S$ do not divide the $k+1$th element of $S$ and

$$r-\sum_{n\in S}\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{b}$$

for some $b\in\mathbb{N}$?

**Example:** For example, for $r=\frac{3}{11}$ we have

$$\frac{3}{11}-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{14}=\frac{1}{770}$$

For $r=\frac{3}{13}$ we have

$$\frac{3}{13}-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{33}=\frac{1}{2145}$$

For $r=\frac{4}{13}$ we have

$$\frac{4}{13}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{19}-\frac{1}{199}-\frac{1}{28089}-\frac{1}{502057679}=\frac{1}{2772681042969479772}$$

**Work so far:** I've created a greedy algorithm that would answer the question in the affirmative if it can be proven to halt.

Step 1: Check whether $r=\frac{1}{b}$ for some $b\in\mathbb{N}$. If yes, set $S=\emptyset$ and you are done. If not go to step $2$.

Step 2: Define $S_1=\{\lceil r^{-1} \rceil\}$ and go to step 3 while setting $i=1$.

Step 3: Check if

$$r-\sum_{n\in S_i}\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{b}$$

for some $b\in\mathbb{N}$. If yes, set $S=S_i$. If not go to step 4.

Step 4: Consider

$$m= \left\lceil \left(r-\sum_{n\in S_i}\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-1}\right\rceil$$

and define $S_{i+1}$ to be

$$S_{i+1}=S_i\cup \{\text{Least }k\geq m:k\not|\prod_{n\in S_i}n\}$$

Go back to step 3 with $i$ incremented to $i+1$.

I have checked this algorithm halts for all $r$ with denominator less than or equal to $10^4$.

**Motivation:** If answered in the affirmative, then this would settle a conjecture I asked about [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4433017/if-sum-n-frac1a-n-2-where-a-n-are-positive-integers-is-there-a-subs/4433099#4433099). The conjecture is:  Let $r$ be a given positive rational and let $T$ be a finite set of rational numbers in $(0,r)$. Does there exist a finite set $S\subset \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\sum_{n\in S}\frac{1}{n}=r$$

but

$$\sum_{n\in R}\frac{1}{n}\not\in T$$

for all $R\in P(S)$? I previously asked this question on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4439406/forming-rational-numbers-using-unique-egyptian-fractions-all-but-one-of-whom-ha) but noone was able to provide a way forward.

Comment: Ernie Croot (also published as Ernest S. Croot III) has several papers on Egyptian fractions that might be relevant.